# Linker Error says Undefined Reference to `my_function`

Tags: makefile, linker, include, kernel

I'm new to kernel programming.
I want to call my function at the scsi drivers.
My function is written in `drivers/md/raid5.c`
I declare My function at raid5.h with `extern void my_function(void)` keyword and I don't forget to `EXPORT_SYMBOL(my_function)` Also, I don't forget to include raid5.h at the scsi_lib.c
I use #include `"../md/raid5.h`" Is there any problem?
I think I'm totally correct.
Here is exact error message.

```
/drivers/scsi/scsi_lib.c:1636: undefined reference to `my_function'
```

Comment: What is value of `MD_RAID456` configuration option? If it is `m`, then raid5 `drivers/md/raid5.c` is compiled as a **module**. In that case the functions defined in this module cannot be used in the code compiled into the **kernel core** (builtin).

Comment: Thanks Tsyvarev. After I change option `m` to `y`. It works!!